# How to create the color background transition from reflectly?

Tags: flutter, animation, transition

Do you have any idea what they did to create this cool effect in flutter? Couldn't find any widget for this use case, since it doesn't seems to be a animation between several pages:

[image]

I tried to use an AnimatedContainer with BoxDecoration and then change the size of that to Something like 99999, but the Container will not go bigger than my display width.

Answer (score 1):

Okey i got it. Turns out that the `Transform.scale` widget can go bigger than your screen size. So I wrapped it around my `AnimatedContainer` Widget and it worked.

If someone has a better solution please let me know.